# Sample rate issue

Tags: trace, spring-cloud-sleuth, zipkin

If the service has a lot of traffic, tracing each invocation and saving the corresponding link log costs a lot, but once the sample rate is set, some trace with errors may be missed. If I want to keep some rate collection, and the trace with errors must be traced, is this possible in `spring-cloud-sleuth`?  If not, is there a solution?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Spring Cloud Sleuth pushes the sampling decision down to the tracer implementation, you need to create either a `SamplerFunction` or a `Sampler` to do this, please see the docs:

- [Sleuth: Sampling](https://docs.spring.io/spring-cloud-sleuth/docs/current/reference/htmlsingle/#features-sampling)
- [Sleuth: Brave Sampling](https://docs.spring.io/spring-cloud-sleuth/docs/current/reference/htmlsingle/#features-brave-sampling)
- [Brave: Sampling](https://github.com/openzipkin/brave/blob/master/brave/README.md#sampling)

**Update:**
Sampling is an early decision because tracing has some overhead and early sampling can save your app from that.
If you want to filter out your spans at the end, you can setup an always sampler and a [`SpanHandler`](https://docs.spring.io/spring-cloud-sleuth/docs/current/reference/htmlsingle/#features-zipkin-custom-reported-spans-brave) where you can access the `Span` (`error`, `tags`, etc.) and you can also keep/drop them based on this (you can inject a sampler to your handler and apply its logic to the rest of your spans).

Comment: But it's still ```head-based``` sampler,  It seems that only the ```tail-based``` sampler can collect the faulty trace.

Comment: Oh, sorry, I misunderstood your question, I edited my answer, please check if it works for you.

Comment: If I implement a ```spanhandler``` , and I will only report logs(for example report to zipkin) where errors have occurred. ```Service 1``` will call ```services 2``` and ```service 3``` remotely. An error occurs when calling ```service 2```, and it is normal when calling ```service 3```. But ```service 3``` cannot perceive the errors of other services,  so log of this span on ```service 3``` node  will be discarded at this time. Then the entire link is incomplete.  Is that a problem?

Comment: This is another reason why Sampling is an early decision. You can try what will Brave do in this case, I think you might end-up with a bunch of incomplete spans.

Comment: Hello, asking an irrelevant question, is ```brave``` no longer maintained? Where did ```Adrian Cole``` go, as if suddenly disappeared in 2021.  And I ask this because spring-cloud-sleuth uses ```brave``` as the tracking library....@Jonatan Ivanov

Comment: There were some changes in Zipkin, not much on Brave. Adrian left the Spring Team, and he is now here: https://www.tetrate.io/about-us/ https://github.com/codefromthecrypt
Sleuth 2.x did heavily depend on Brave but in 3.0 Sleuth abstracted the tracing libraries away and can support multiple tracer implementations (i.e.: Brave and OTel at the moment).