# Conditionally propagation of span ids using Spring Sleuth

Tags: spring, microservices, spring-cloud-sleuth, zipkin

I'm working a project with tens of services, using Spring sleuth and zipkin, but I was wondering if there is any way to conditionally propagate logs to zipkin server.

Actually, would be perfect if the log was propagated only when The distributed transaction failed, (like using a saga pattern). The case is, we have a huge workload (millions of request per hour) and we are interest only in failed request.

Answer (score 0):

You can't propagate logs to Zipkin, you can publish Spans.
Depending on your needs, you can use a `SamplerFunction`, a `Sampler` or a `SpanHandler`, see this answer: https://stackoverflow.com/a/69981877/971735