# How to specify which paths should be traced by Sleuth with Zipkin?

Tags: spring-boot, microservices, trace, spring-cloud-sleuth, zipkin

I'm looking for some information about how to specify which endpoints should be traced by Sleuth. By far, all i've found in sleuth docs was information about how to specify which endpoints shouldn't be traced. I'm going in the opposite direction, so, is there any properties or configs that control this flow?

Answer (score 0):

Spring Cloud Sleuth pushes the sampling decision down to the tracer implementation, you need to create either a `SamplerFunction` or a `Sampler` to do this, please see the docs:

- [Sleuth: Sampling](https://docs.spring.io/spring-cloud-sleuth/docs/current/reference/htmlsingle/#features-sampling)
- [Sleuth: Brave Sampling](https://docs.spring.io/spring-cloud-sleuth/docs/current/reference/htmlsingle/#features-brave-sampling)
- [Brave: Sampling](https://github.com/openzipkin/brave/blob/master/brave/README.md#sampling)

Comment: **For mods**: the answer for this question is exactly the same as the answer for a different question: [Sample rate issue](https://stackoverflow.com/a/69981877/971735). Please before you delete it: read both questions, read the documentation of Spring Cloud Sleuth and you can also consult with a maintainer here in the comments section. :)

Comment: @jean-françois-fabre ^